# Lost position when mouse draging map

Tags: openlayers

Set extent to view:

```
var view = new ol.View({
            projection: 'EPSG:3857',
            center: center,
            zoom: 11,
            minZoom: 11,
            extent : [
                LeftPointX,
                LeftPointY,
                RightPointX,
                RightPointY
            ],
            maxZoom: 16
        });
```

When I zoom map on left corner areas and trying to drag map, the position when I focused is lost. Map goes to another coordinate. When I remove view.extent It works normaly.

Examples here:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/umid/x4m4g1wg/2/

Comment: Its because of your extent. On lower zoom levels a outer margin around the extent is lost. So check your extent at http://boundingbox.klokantech.com (epsg:4326 i think)

Maybe you should choose a bigger extent.

Comment: The extent property only guarantees that the map centre does not fall outside the bounds.  It does not constrain the edges directly.  Like @MichaelJS said, you may want a larger extent.

Comment: Is it possible to change extent dynamically when view is changed ?

Comment: You could try to use the 
`view.on('change:center')` event 
and set the extent there - something like 
`ol.View().set('extent',newextent)`

see http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.View.html

Comment: var extent = [4179159, 7499612, 4197368, 7542408];
view.on('change:center', function(evt){   
    var r = evt.target.getResolution();
    map.getView().set('extent', [
        extent[0] * r,
        extent[1] * r,
        extent[2] * r,
        extent[3] * r
    ]);    
}); Does not help

Comment: I see now in the API-Documentation under "Observable Properties" extent is not part of it. So you won't receive it with the .get(value) method nor you can can set it with .set()-method. 

Maybe calculateExtent() will help.. dont know
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.View.html

Btw: why would you limit the extent in the first place when the user can change it when he is panning the map? Just set an extent which is suitable for the application in the beginning.